# How do I detect if a nav button has been deselected?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jquery to add a class when the collapsible button in bootstrap is pushed. What I want to happen is remove that class when the button is pushed again (hiding the menu).

One of my ideas would be to add a count? Each time count % 2 == 0, remove/add the class etc. Would that work?

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid home">
        <img src="http://terrimoore.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/2014-02-06-los-angeles1.jpg" id="la" />

            <h1 class="jumbo-header">Enigma Audio</h1>

    </div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#navbutton").click(function(){
        $("img").addClass("filtered");
    });
});
```

Comment: Better use `toggleClass("filtered");`

Comment: Have a look over here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass

Comment: The count idea would work, but it doesn't make much sense as you don't need that much info. Better to just flip a boolean value or just add the class if it doesn't exist and remove if it does

Comment: toggleClass was exactly what I was looking for. I think I was overthinking it. Thank you divy3993

Comment: @FroyT Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want `.toggleClass("class-name");`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#navbutton").click(function() {
     $("img").toggleClass("filtered");
   });
 });
```